# How to set margin right value for a Text in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a card view as follow

[image]

There, the red coloured text row has 2 `Text` fields. I want to keep a space between the `Text` field in the right and the right side of the card(As exact same as text lines in black color). Below is my implementation. How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance!

```
Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
         child: Center(
           child: Align(
             alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
             child: Card(
                 child: InkWell(
                   splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
                   onTap: (){
                     print('Card Tapped');
                   },
                   child: Container(
                     width: 380,
                     height: 140,
                     child: Align(
                       alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                       child: new Column(
                         children : <Widget>[
                           Container(
                             margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, top: 25),
                             alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                             child: Row(
                               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                               children: [
                                 Text('Account Number',
                                     textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                     style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 15, color: Colors.redAccent),
                                   ),
//                                 Spacer(flex: 1),
                                 Text('12345678',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 15, color: Colors.redAccent),) //<------- This text field should keep a space from right
                               ],
                             ),
                           ),
                           Container(
                             margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, top: 15),
                             alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                             child: Text('Available Amount                                   LKR 1200.00', //<------- I will re-implement these too in a Row once I figure out this 
                                 style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 15),
                               ),
                           ),
                           Container(
                             margin: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 21, top: 15),
                             alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                             child: Text('Active',
                               style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 15),
                             ),
                           ),
                         ],
                       ),
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
             ),
           ),
         )
     ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add right margin like below

```
margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, top: 25, right: 25),
```

**Code:**

```
                 Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, top: 25, right: 25),
                            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                            child: Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: [
                                Text('Account Number',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 15, color: Colors.redAccent),
                                ),
//                                 Spacer(flex: 1),
                                Text('12345678',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 15, color: Colors.redAccent),) //<------- This text field should keep a space from right
                              ],
                            ),
          

            ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it right. You just need a padding field:

```
                           Container(
     THIS ------------->     padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20, right: 20),
                             margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25, top: 25),
                             alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                             child: Row(
                               mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                               children: [
                                 Text('Account Number',
                                     textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                     style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 15, color: Colors.redAccent),
                                   ),
                                 Text('12345678',
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.right,
                                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,fontSize: 15, color: Colors.redAccent),) //<------- This text field should keep a space from right
                               ],
                             ),
                           ),
```